# How to split vector with strings

Tags: r

I have a vector with gene names where several elements in the vector contains more than one gene name, separated with a comma. How can I separate the elements of this vector and get a long vector with each gene name as a separate element of the vector? I have tried strsplit but that just give me the two or more gene names as separated strings but still in the same element of the vector... /Frida

```
genes = c("PGD", "CDA", "MROH7,TTC4", "PGM1")
```

and I want to separate the element `"MROH7,TTC4"` into the two elements `"MROH7"` and `"TTC4"`

Comment: Welcome on SO. Could you please provide an [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi,the vector looks like this: genes = ("PGD", "CDA", "MROH7,TTC4", "PGM1") and I want to separate the element "MROH7,TTC4" into the two elements "MROH7" and "TTC4".

Answer (score 9):

This will split your string at every comma:

```
genes = c("PGD", "CDA", "MROH7,TTC4", "PGM1")
genes.split = unlist(strsplit(genes, ","))

genes.split
[1] "PGD"   "CDA"   "MROH7" "TTC4"  "PGM1"
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option is `scan`, which will also eat white space.

```
scan(text=genes, what='', sep=',', strip.white=TRUE)
```